# How to Unpivot Data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, recursive-query, unpivot

Help Guys,
I Have Table

Table Product:

```
| id | product | quantity |
| 1  | tea     | 2        |
| 2  | juice   | 3        |
```

I want to Select use all of them to become:

```
| id | product |
| 1  | tea     |
| 1  | tea     |
| 2  | juice   |
| 2  | juice   |
| 2  | juice   |
```

How Can I Query it? thank you

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a recursive query, available in MySQL 8.0:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id, product, quantity from mytable
    union all
    select id, product, quantity - 1 from cte where quantity > 1
)
select id, product from cte
```

Comment: did you mean i need to have another table ? cmiiw

Comment: @TondoKtbffh: no, just replace `mytable` with the actual name of your table.

Answer (score 1):

Hello hope this will help you.

```
SELECT a.id , a.product , a.quantity 
FROM Product a 
cross join 
(select * from seq_1_to_10000) b 
where a.quantity >= b.seq
```

**Upvote if you find useful.**